Присоединительная конструкция может быть общим элементом для ССП?
(1) Стало темно(?) и пошел дождь(?) ЧТО было совсем некстати.
(2) Стало темно(?) и пошел дождь(?) ЭТО [также НУ] совсем некстати.
Как выбрать знаки  в двух вариантах этого предложения и объяснить их по Розенталю. Есть ли тут общий элемент, отменяющий запятую перед союзом И? Какой знак поставить перед ЭТО (тире или единый знак)?
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
В чем трудность?  С первым предложением все понятно: запятой нет, общее придаточное. Оно приведено для сравнения.
А у второго какая грамматика, БСП? Больше похоже на присоединение, а присоединительный член может быть общим элементом? Примеры хорошо бы увидеть...
Ну и ответы тоже: есть же у нас участники, хорошо знающие хорошие грамматику и правописание.

Второй ответ по просьбе:
Запишите, пжста, ваш окончательный вариант предложения в ответе.
Дело в том, что сначала было два набора слов (плюс вариация), потом подключился третий, да ещё и с контекстом. Вот он, выверенный до мелочей вариант:
Стало темно, и пошел дождь, – это было совсем некстати.
Ну а в первом моём ответе сразу было обозначено: «Нет, с этим предложением [причём речь шла о первом наборе без запятой перед и] не всё понятно. При такой последовательности слов не объединяются две первые единицы следующим за ними придаточным».
И далее, можно сказать в завершение, я повторяюсь: «При таком порядке совсем не просматривается объединяющая роль присоединения».

ОК! Благодарю вас за интерес к теме. Надеюсь, что чувство прекрасного будет всегда помогать вам в вашей работе с текстами))

Спасибо, Sharon!

В чем трудность? С первым предложением все понятно: 
запятой нет, общее придаточное. Оно приведено для сравнения.

Стало темно и пошел дождь, что было совсем некстати.
Нет, с этим предложением не всё понятно. При такой последовательности слов не объединяются две первые единицы следующим за ними придаточным. Из-за отсутствия контекста непонятно, относится ли "некстати" к "стало темно".
Объединить их можно, когда они войдут, например, в подчинённую роль:
Тыры пыры шарли буба, потому что стало темно и пошел дождь.
А у второго какая грамматика, БСП? Больше похоже на присоединение... 

Да, похоже, и если не хотите это присоединение вынести "за скобки", то тогда такие варианты:
Стало темно, и пошел дождь, это совсем некстати. – невзрачно
Стало темно, и пошел дождь – это совсем некстати. – невнятно
Стало темно, и пошел дождь, – это совсем некстати. – зачем?
Стало темно и пошел дождь – это совсем некстати. – ...
Стало темно и пошел дождь, – это совсем некстати. – ...
При таком порядке совсем не просматривается объединяющая роль присоединения.
Для сравнения.
Первые две основы можно связать "своим" придаточным (в разговоре):
– Пока мы болтали, стало темно и пошел дождь, это совсем некстати.
– Пока мы болтали, стало темно и пошел дождь. Ну совсем некстати.
– Пока мы болтали, стало темно и пошел дождь, – ну совсем некстати.
Простор велик, пишите письма от руки...

А зачем подумывать предложения, которых нет в вопросе?

@Серж Чтоб было нагляднее. Как пример того, при какой структуре и контексте не ставится запятая перед союзом И.

Александр, спасибо за ответ и ваши труды) Вы, как я вижу, хорошо повеселились, отвечая на такой серьезный вопрос)

В справочниках ничего не говорится о присоединительной конструкции как общего элемента. И это логично. Присоединительная конструкция не может быть общем элементом из-за своей семантики. Присоединительная конструкция сообщает дополнительную информацию, разъяснения или замечания, синтаксически она не зависима.

Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня.  Действительно, логично считать, что присоед. конструкция общим элементом не является.  Да и знак в приведенном предложении (2) скорее запятая и тире, одного тире недостаточно. // Но тут такая проблема: присоед. конструкцию иногда сложно отличить от БСП. Здесь у нас оценочное суждение. Так это присоединение или БСП? И каково ваше решение по пунктуации в предложении (2)?

Если считать это БСП, то тогда какие отношения между его частями?

В обоих случаях я бы поставил запятую .

Вопрос был в том, можно ли считать присоединительную конструкцию общим элементом. Если приплести общую придаточную часть, то это и так понятно, что запятой не должно быть.


Где контекст? Вот контекст!

— Может, вернемся?  Погода  ненадежная...
— До деревни километров десять, успеем дойти.
Не успели! Туча стремительно приближалась, закрывая небосклон.  Стало темно(?) и пошел дождь(?) это было совсем некстати (или: вот уж совсем некстати). Ни палатки, ни плащей у нас не было.

А это найдено у Розенталя, п. 9. Совершенно случайно))
Примечание. Часто при наличии перед присоединительным 
предложением слова это между частями бессоюзного сложного 
предложения ставятся запятая и тире: Русская 
интеллигенция росла и развивалась в условиях совершенно 
зверских, — это неоспоримо (М. Г.). [См. § 46, п. 1.]

Запятая и тире могут ставиться также перед 
присоединительным предложением, содержащим дополнительное 
замечание: Посёлок Первомайский был самым старым 
шахтёрским посёлком в этом районе, — от него, собственно, 
и начался город (Ф.).


Мы тут сначала подумали и решили, что присоединительная конструкция общим элементом быть не может. Или все-таки может?


Приведите, пжста,  предложения по контексту, соответствующие вашей точке зрения (с расставленными знаками препинания)

Sharon, вот вы добавили всего одно слово "было", и стало приятней читать, и можно уже и не ставить запятую перед И, а присоединение считать общим: Стало темно и пошел дождь, – это было совсем некстати. // Так что вариантов на голое предложение всегда куча. // И помните, говорили мы как-то об объединении простых предложений в одно целое (как однородные члены) даже без общих синтаксических частей (когда эта общность подкреплена контекстом и соответствующе звучит).

Александр, где же ваш ответ по контексту? Ведь нам нужно дополнить правило Розенталя! Контрольные вопросы: (1) Можно ли в принципе считать присоединение общим элементом? (2) В заданном предложение это присоединение или нет? (3) Какой знак ставим? (4) Нужна ли запятая перед И? //  Запишите ваш вариант предложения, пжста.

У вас уже другое предложение. Его вариант я написал (без запятой и с единым знаком). Можно обойтись и одним тире, по смыслу и по интонации это присоединение. Можно ли его считать общим? Почему нет, если это заложено в задумке, в смысле. Пространные правила много чего разрешают...

А почему Розенталь не рассматривает эту конструкцию в теме БСП? Почему у него только пояснение, да еще в препозиции? Запятая и тире – серьезный знак, как мне кажется, он не способствует объединению.  Предложения явно однородные, но может ли их объединить присоед. констр.? Я до сих пор сомневаюсь. Еще и примеров нет.

Розенталь дал направления, в большом смысле слова. Если кто-то серьёзно проанализирует современную пунктуацию и создаст внятное дополнение, или расширит имеющуюся трактовку правила, или напишет статью о своём видении письменных символов, – честь ему и хвала. // Сомневаешься в знаке – не пиши, а если пишешь – не сомневайся. // Вот я и даю  "оценку" этому набору слов (а на самом деле другому) в своём ответе, что все варианты сомнительны.

Ответ на комментарий по теме
Спасибо, Александр, за "набор слов" — я старалась))

Сомнительные предложения? Да, возмможно, но я так и не решила, что с ними не так.

Розенталь дал направления в большом смысле слова? Безусловно! И он, конечно, не мог решить для нас и за нас абсолютно все задачи.

Приход нового Розенталя я тоже приветствую, да не скоро это случится, если судить по уровню знаний большинства пользователей. Печальная картина! Эти бы правила осмыслить и понять, не до хорошего.

Правда, вот "революционные настроения" всякого рода, напротив, не приветствую. Были тут у нас учители со своими программами, которые много чего наговорили, да и сейчас встречаются.

Письменные символы? Красиво говорите, но давайте ближе к делу. Посмотрим, как мы сами их осмыслили.

Мой выбор: Стало темно, и пошел дождь, — вот уж совсем некстати.


Обоснование. Тире не подойдет, так как в первой части сложный синтаксис (две предикативные основы). Единый знак  подтверждает присоединительный характер второй части, так что общего элемента здесь нет. Соответственно, ставим запятую.

И немного об эстетике. Меня иногда спрашивали: вы серьезно так считаете: правильно то, что красиво.  Серьезно, очень даже!)) Выбранный вариант кажется мне красивым, а все, что без запятой и с тире — схематичным и жалким, как будто раздетым. Ну это я так вижу))


Под "набором" я имел в виду порядок слов, т. к. об этом писал уже в ответе два раза. И этот набор изменился, первоначально было "некрасиво" ("сомнительно"). Поэтому я и сейчас против объединения первых двух основ. Ну и эстетика – вещь историческая, подвластная течениям.

Спасибо за ваше мнение. Интересной стала ваша риторика, как будто вы прошли обучение на курсах.  Откуда у вас такие мысли, вас просто не узнать)  Диахронная эстетика... Но на текущий момент эту эстетику как-то можно определить. Вот вы про символы говорите, но неужели не видите, что без запятой совсем не то.  Здесь три синтагмы, но две фразы. Ну просто золотое сечение отрезка))

Дык я ж об этом и сказал, что не вижу смысла в объединении первых частей при таком наборе слов :) Запятая ставится.

Запишите,  пжста, ваш  окончательный  вариант предложения в ответе
